# value sent to controller by using JS

Tags: javascript

I'm new to codiginiter and it's still developing.

I'm trying to send a JS value to codiginiter controller but I'm getting errors. Firebug says syntax error. But when I correct it, another syntax error is being shown.

I think the problem is with my script. Can anyone can figure out what's wrong? All I want is to send username value to method in controller. Following alert is triggered when I press the button (tested and working).

```js
<script type="text/javascript">   
    $(function(){
        $("#postAnswer").click(function(){  // passing down the event 
            alert("checked");
            $.post('<?php echo base_url(); ?>homepage/postanswer', {
                //username:document.getElementById('username').value
                username:<?php  $ques[0]->username ?> 
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `username: "<?php echo $ques[0]->username; ?>"`

Comment: Can you post the code that is actually generated and sent to the client? Seeing your php code is not really relevant

Comment: @dfsq in codiginiter how can i retrieve value of that username dude.?

Comment: Just as any other POST parameter: `$_POST['username']` or with CI special request object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct way to echo PHP variable would be to JSON encode it first (and use `echo`):

```
$.post('<?php echo base_url(); ?>homepage/postanswer', {
    username: <?php echo json_encode($ques[0]->username); ?>
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what the error is with FireBug, it's like an issue of needing to enclose the `<?php $ques[0]->username ?>` in quotes to make it a string.

```
username: "<?php $ques[0]->username ?>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use append('username',$query[0]->yourdataname)